# how can i call a test method defined in Visual studio to a code module in Ranorex?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ranorex

hi I am trying to create a repository in ranorex to compile a couple of test methods in visual studio.  First I connect to uri client machine and try to get metadata of the schema Items ID

```
[TestMethod TestCategory("MetaData-FullSchema"),]
public void Get_SchemaViews_SchemaItemsId()
{
    string error = "";
    IEnumerable<JToken> Pchild, Achild, AaChild;
    JObject actualOutput;
    var ids = new List<JToken>();
    int i = 0;
    actualOutput = getOutPut();

    Pchild = actualOutput["schemaViews"].Children().Children().Children();
    foreach (JProperty lis in Pchild)
    {
        if (lis.Name == "schemaItemIds")
        {
            ids = lis.Children().Children().ToList();
        }
    }

    if (ids.Count == 3)
    {
        Achild = actualOutput["schemaItems"].Children();
        string[] names = { "Priority", "Severity" };
        for (int j = 0; j < ids.Count; j++)
        {
            foreach (JProperty pro in Achild)
            {
                if (ids[j].ToString() == pro.Name)
                {
                    AaChild = pro.Children().Children();
                    foreach (JProperty InPro in AaChild)
                    {
                        if (InPro.Name == "schemaItemId")
                        {
                            if (InPro.Value.ToString() == pro.Name)
                                i++;
                            else
                                error += "\nschemaItems and schemaItemsId does not match in" + InPro.Path;
                        }
                        else if (InPro.Name == "name")
                        {
                            if (InPro.Value.ToString() == names[j])
                                i++;
                            else
                                error += "\nError in name at" + InPro.Path;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        error = "Error in the number of elements at SchemaItemsId in SchemaViews.";

    if (MetaData_Results.ContainsKey("Get_SchemaViews_SchemaItemsId"))
        MetaData_Results.Remove("Get_SchemaViews_SchemaItemsId");
    MetaData_Results.Add("Get_SchemaViews_SchemaItemsId", error);
    Pirnt_MetaData_Results();
    Assert.IsTrue(i == 6, error);
}
```

Using package such as newtonsoft and restsharp . The connection setup is done as

```
Uri siteUri = new Uri("");
IRestResponse response = null;
var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = siteUri;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  Ranorex is used to create recordings of UI tests.  Under the cover, it is entirely .NET (either VB.NET or C#).  Calling a method is simply a matter of adding a reference between the 2 projects and calling the method, no?  Here we do the exact opposite.  We create a test method consisting of simply a call to Ranorex run configuration.  This article on Ranorex web site shows how to Ranorex integration in TFS/MTM/Visual Studio: http://www.ranorex.com/news/article/howto-test-automation-with-tfs-and-ranorex.html

Comment: thanks . I was just playing around with ranorex. this explains a lot

Comment: Ranorex is really good to build coded UI tests by non programmers...